# Fizzbuzz problem: "fizz" condition doesn't pass unless "buzz" does as well

Tags: java

I was doing a simple `fizzbuzz` problem in Java and encountered a bug that I cannot find for the life of me. The "fizz" is not added to the result unless the number is also divisible by 5.

actual: `["1","2","3","4","buzz","6","7","8","9","buzz","11","12","13","14","fizzbuzz"]`

expected: `["1","2","fizz","4","buzz","fizz","7","8","fizz","buzz","11","fizz","13","14","fizzbuzz"]`

```
public List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            String word = "";
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                word += "fizz";
            } if (i % 5 == 0) {
                word += "buzz";
            } else {
                word = String.valueOf(i);
            }
            result.add(word);
        }
     return result;
    }
```

Comment: sure you aren't missing an "else" ?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. This is a critical skill to learn as you learn how to write code.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `if` block instead of one.

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
   word += "fizz";
} if (i % 5 == 0) {
   word += "buzz";
} else {
   word = String.valueOf(i);
}
```

In the above block first condition is if the `i` is divisible by 3 and immediately it will check if the `i` is divisible by 5 else it will execute the else part.

In case of `i` being divisible `3` and not divisible by `5` you will always get the `i` value.

for your requirement you could do as follows

```
if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
   word = "fizzbuzz";
} else if (i % 3 == 0) {
   word = "fizz";
} else if (i % 5 == 0) {
   word = "buzz";
} else {
   word = String.valueOf(i);
}
```

This way first you are check if the value is both divisible by 3 and 5 if not then divisible by 3 if not then divisible by 5 and finally else part.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static List<String> fizzBuzz(int n) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>(n);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        boolean mulThree = i % 3 == 0;
        boolean mulFive = i % 5 == 0;

        if (mulThree && mulFive)
            res.add("FizzBuzz");
        else if (mulThree)
            res.add("Fizz");
        else if (mulFive)
            res.add("Buzz");
        else
            res.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    return res;
}
```